# jquery execute function while ajax response is loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How can I execute a function that will run while the client is waiting for the server response? Here is my code. I looked up and found a .load() function, but how does that fit into this? Any help would be great! Thanks

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "mail.php",
    data: {name: name.val(), email: email.val(), phone: phone.val(), subject: subject.val(), message: message.val()}
    }).done(function(){
        alert("Your message was sent. We will be in contact with you shortly.");
        window.location="index.html";
});
```

Comment: What you want execute while the client is waiting response?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what I'm doing, it sounded best? I guess its not though?

Comment: And fwiw anything that you write in beforeSend is going to block the ajax request from firing until that code block has completed. So it actually doesn't do what you want at all.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The very next line of code you write after
You call $.ajax() will run while the browser is waiting for a response.

So:

```
$.ajax();
yourAwesomeFN();
```

XhttpRequests are asynchronous. No extra work required.

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked in [the "beforeSend" param](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax_Events).

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
    url: "mail.php",
    data: {name: name.val(), email: email.val(), phone: phone.val(), subject: subject.val(), message: message.val()},

   beforeSend: function(){
     // Handle the beforeSend event
   },
   complete: function(){
     // Handle the complete event
   }
   // ......
 });
```

Comment: same comment as the other answer: beforeSend is going to block the ajax request from firing. This does not accomplish what the question had asked of executing code in the browser while the ajax request was being processed on the server.

Answer (score 1):

You can't execute a function *while* another is being executed in JS, being it mono-threaded: you can do stuff **before** and **after** though - are you looking for a way to setup a message / spinner to be shown while waiting? Check [beforeSend](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) option in `$.ajax()` call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "mail.php",
    data: {name: name.val(), email: email.val(), phone: phone.val(), subject: subject.val(), message: message.val()}
    beforeSend : function(){

        // do your stuff here

    }
    }).done(function(){
        alert("Your message was sent. We will be in contact with you shortly.");
        window.location="index.html";
});
```

Comment: beforeSend is going to block the ajax request from firing. This does not accomplish what the question had asked of executing code in the browser while the ajax request was being processed on the server.

Comment: You're totally right, thank you for letting me have clue on proper `beforeSend` purpose.