# How can I show a gif before Jquery POST results available?

Tags: jquery, html

Following JQuery code:

```
    $.post("resultdates.php", 
    { number:  number,
    language:  language
    }, function(result) {
        $("#messager").html(result);
    });
```

It takes some time before "result" for the html #messager are available.
I want show a spinner.gif in #messager before the result available!
How can I do that?

Comment: No it is no duplicate! I want to use $.post instead ajax!

Comment: Can't you just add an loading give to your page, add an id to it and a `style="display: none"`. And then use `$('#id').show()` just before the code you just posted?

Comment: You can find your answer here => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12125510/jquery-execute-function-while-ajax-response-is-loading

Comment: You can find your answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12125510/jquery-execute-function-while-ajax-response-is-loading